# How to write function to either Encode or Decode Base64 from either a string or path of file?

Tags: powershell, switch-statement, base64

I have one function that will convert a string to base64 that works with simple strings.
However something like:

```
$String = "$program = "notepad"; start $program"
```

Does not work, the extra quotes in the middle break the function. I tried using a script block but it does not work exactly right either. This is my first hurdle.
This is that function:

```
function B64-FromString{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
    
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
    [string]$Text
    )
    
    $Text = {$Text}
    $Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($Text)
    $EncodedText =[Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes)
    $EncodedText
}
```

My next function takes a file path as a parameter and converts the contents of the file to base64 then returns the converted code. This function works as intended.
This is that function:

```
function B64-FromFile {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
    
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
    [Alias("source")]
    [string]$so,

    [Parameter (Mandatory = $False)]
    [Alias("output")]
    [string]$Path, 

    [Parameter (Mandatory = $False)]
    [Alias("FileName")]
    [string]$File 

    )   

    if (!$File) { $File = "converted.txt" }

    if (!$Path) { $Path = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") }
    
    $FilePath = ($Path+"\"+$File)

    $converted = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes((Get-Content -Path $so -Raw -Encoding UTF8)))
    
    return $converted
}
```

The end goal here is to have a single function that will have a parameter switch for encode/decode.
And another switch for fromString/fromFile

i think using switches some where along the lines of:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Position=0)]
    [string[]]
    $m
)
$mode = switch ( $m )
{
    "enc"  { "encode-function" }
    "dec" { "decode-function" }
}

}
```

and another parameter and switch to distinguish between recieving the input from a string or file contents.

I'm still learning powershell and having a hard time conceptualizing this particular methodology.

Comment: `$String = "$program = "notepad"; start $program"` is a syntactic error, if you don't want the variable `$program` to be interpolated in the string then wrap everything in another layer of single quote: `$String = '"$program = "notepad"; start $program"'` if you want the variable to be expanded, then you can use a [_double quote here-string_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2#here-strings)

Comment: What is the intention for `$Text = {$Text}`? This just assigns a scriptblock to `$Text`. I think the line should be removed completely.

Comment: ```$String = "`$program = ""notepad""; start $program"``` should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after about 10 hours of experimenting I came up with a solution that I am pretty proud of.

Still willing to take any constructive criticism.

```
function b64 {
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="encFile")]
param(
    [Parameter(Position=0, ParameterSetName="encFile")]
    [string]
    $encFile,

    [Parameter(Position=0, ParameterSetName="encString")]
    [string]
    $encString,

    [Parameter(Position=0, ParameterSetName="decFile")]
    [string]
    $decFile,

    [Parameter(Position=0, ParameterSetName="decString")]
    [string]
    $decString

)

if ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "encFile") {
        $encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes((Get-Content -Path $encFile -Raw -Encoding UTF8)))
        return $encoded
        }

elseif ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "encString") {
        $File = "$env:TEMP\foob64.txt"
        Set-Content -NoNewline -Path $File -Value $encString    
        $encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes((Get-Content -Path $File -Raw -Encoding UTF8)))
        Remove-Item $File
        return  $encoded
        }

elseif ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "decFile") {
        $data = Get-Content $decFile
        $decoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($data))
        return $decoded     
        }

elseif ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "decString") {
        $File = "$env:TEMP\foob64.txt"
        Set-Content -NoNewline -Path $File -Value $decString
        $data = Get-Content $File       
        $decoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($data))
        Remove-Item $File
        return $decoded
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the encoding of strings didn't work. There was an '%' added on the end of string somehow. The coding of strings can be done easier this way (I didn't check the file params):

```
function b64 {
  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="encString")]
  param(
      [Parameter(Position=0, ParameterSetName="encFile")]
      [string]
      $encFile,
  
      [Parameter(Position=0, ParameterSetName="encString")]
      [string]
      $encString,
  
      [Parameter(Position=0, ParameterSetName="decFile")]
      [string]
      $decFile,
  
      [Parameter(Position=0, ParameterSetName="decString")]
      [string]
      $decString
  
  )
  
  if ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "encFile") {
          $encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes((Get-Content -Path $encFile -Raw -Encoding UTF8)))
          return $encoded
          }
  
  elseif ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "encString") {   
          [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($encString))          
          return  $encoded
          }
  
  elseif ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "decFile") {
          $data = Get-Content $decFile
          $decoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($data))
          return $decoded     
          }
  
  elseif ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "decString") {
          $decoded = [Text.Encoding]::Utf8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String($decString))
          return $decoded
          }
}
```